# Change cursor of a pop out panel

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, popup, cursor

how can i change the cursor when my cursor is only within this pop out panel and not in the main stage ?

```
private function launchPopUp(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
     panel = new Panel();
          panel.width = stage.stageWidth;
          panel.height = stage.stageHeight;
     panel.setStyle("borderAlpha", 1);
     PopUpManager.addPopUp(panel, this, true);
          PopUpManager.centerPopUp(panel);
}
```

Would appreciate if anyone could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to change the mousecursor. The trick is to hide the mousecursor and replace it with a sprite.

```
function launchPopUp(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
     panel = new Panel();
     panel.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveFunc);
     panel.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseOutFunc);
     panel.width = stage.stageWidth;
     panel.height = stage.stageHeight;
     panel.setStyle("borderAlpha", 1);
     PopUpManager.addPopUp(panel, this, true);
     PopUpManager.centerPopUp(panel);
}

function mouseMoveFunc(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    Mouse.hide();
    customMouseSprite.visible = true;
    customMouseSprite.x = e.stageX;
    customMouseSprite.y = e.stageY;
}

function mouseOutFunc(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    Mouse.show();
    customMouseSprite.visible = false;;
}
```

You also need to call the mouseOutFunc when the popup is closed. the customMouseSprite has to be on the top layer of your stage. customMouseSprite can either be a sprite or movieclip (in fact any displayobject).

Comment: thanks for the reply. But how do i create the customMouseSprite.

Comment: I have made an flash professional simple custom mouse sprite and a pure actionscript only version. Both can be found in this zip: http://www.megaupload.com/?d=1CY5I9HI

Comment: @desmond was that zip helpfull?